# Appium click on element that keeps changing location

Tags: python, appium

I am using Appium + Python to automate testing an iOS app. I got stuck on clicking on element from a list that is generated dynamically by searching for bluetooth devices. The problem is I find the element I want but when I try to click on it sometimes it clicks on the wrong element because the elements are generated automatically so by the time click command is sent the element has changed location. and I have many bluetooth devices around me so the list keeps on growing and shrinking depending on the channel conditions. 
is there a way to make it this process more reliable?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share some of your code? How are you finding your elements? How are you clicking?

Comment: Thanks Mike. I am finding the element using this code                                              
element = WebDriverWait(driver, self.maximum_timeout).until(
                    expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((MobileBy.ACCESSIBILITY_ID, element_locator))). this snippet is part of a function called wait_get_element() once this returns I am calling click on it. I hope it is clear how I am doing it and thanks for your help.

Comment: Ok, I was hoping maybe you were doing your assignment well before the click as that's the only easy solution I see. You're not so there's no time to cut out.

Wrap your code very tightly and retry if things don't go the way you expect them?

A physical solution might be the final solution. Move away form the other BT sources, isolate the phone in some way (water/metal/strong RF signals).

Comment: I have a Ramsey box if I wanted only one BT source. However part of the test is to find out how the app connection "setup" behaves in a noisy environment.